# How can I convert SD2 to WAV? Would Python, FFmpeg or shell based sd2 audio file converters work?

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, pydub

I have 3TBs+ of sd2 (Sound Designer II) files that I need to convert to wave files. I had hoped to write a simple script to go through all the folders recursively (this I have no issues with - it is the conversion).

I am not sure if a codec can be imported into FFmpeg? It seems like there was a core-audio codec for older versions of FFmpeg that worked with sd2. I don't see anything remotely current, and all my computers and OS versions are too recent.

Added code. I have a list `codecs` with all the codecs. Then I run the following. It works with mp3s.

```
in_file = "/Volumes/SOUNDS/Style.sd2"
out_file = "/Volumes/SOUNDS/Style.wav"

for i in codecs:
    subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i ' + i, in_file ,out_file ])
```

Comment: Why don't you just try those options on one file, see if you can get any of them to work, and then worry about how to loop through all the files later? However you do it, you can have a Python script automate everything.

Comment: That is what I have been doing, sadly, no dice.

Comment: Alright. I'd leave out the part about looping through the files; that's a totally independent question. I'd also make it clear, from the title, exactly what you are asking. And I'd also update your post to be very clear that you currently have no working way to convert those files, and that you're asking us if we know of or could help you find a way.

Comment: Updated. Thanks

Comment: rather don't use `'-i ' + i` but put as separated elements on list `'-i', i`

Comment: to work with all files in nested folders you can use `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder): ...`

Comment: @furas I have tried various configurations including `'-i', i` regretfully, it is an issue with sd2 being depreciated. I am familiar with nested folders. For me, it is the conversion that is the bottle neck. Thanks.

Comment: so your problem is only `ffmpeg`, not code in Python. You should test `ffmpeg` directly in console/terminal and you should get the same result. Maybe you should search in `ffmpeg` [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/)